# get a list of values from user in streamlit app

Tags: python, streamlit

I want to get a list of values from user, but I have no idea how to perform.
I tried with code as follows but this is not the correct way.

```
import streamlit as st

collect_numbers = lambda x : [str(x)]

numbers = st.text_input("PLease enter numbers")

st.write(collect_numbers(numbers))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a tuple, list or iterable. For example,

```py
import streamlit as st  # 1.18.1

numbers = [st.number_input(f"Enter number {i}") for i in range(4)]
st.write(numbers)
```

Or text:

```py
prompts = "Name", "Age", "Favorite animal", "Birth date", "Favorite color"
answers = [st.text_input(x) for x in prompts]

for prompt, answer in zip(prompts, answers):
    st.write(f"Your {prompt.lower()} is {answer}")
```

Or a mix:

```py
prompts = "Name", "Age", "Favorite animal", "Birth date", "Favorite color"
inputs = (
    st.text_input,
    lambda p: st.number_input(p, value=0),
    st.text_input,
    st.date_input,
    st.color_picker
)
answers = [fn(p) for p, fn in zip(prompts, inputs)]

for prompt, answer in zip(prompts, answers):
    st.write(f"Your {prompt.lower()} is {answer}")
```

You could put this in a form if you want to handle a final submission after all inputs are filled:

```py
prompts = {
    "Name": st.text_input,
    "Age": lambda p: st.number_input(p, value=0),
    "Favorite animal": st.text_input,
    "Birth date": st.date_input,
    "Favorite color": st.color_picker,
}

with st.form("info"):
    answers = [fn(p) for p, fn in prompts.items()]

    if st.form_submit_button("Submit"):
        if all(answers):
            for prompt, answer in zip(prompts, answers):
                st.write(f"Your {prompt.lower()} is {answer}")
        else:
            st.error("Please fill all fields")
```

Streamlit has pretty powerful form handling, so these can be extended much further, but I don't want to speculate too much on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Need more info about what you are trying to do. If you need some specified values you can try using diferent text inputs as columns. You can display as many columns as you want, the following code is an easy example.

```
col1, col2 = st.columns(2)

with col1:
     val1 = st.text_input("Enter first value")

with col2:
     val2 = st.text_input("Enter second value")

list_val = [val1,val2]
```

Also you can request the user to enter the values as coma separated, then use that to make the list that you want

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is more close to what I am doing now. 
I want to filter a data frame ids columns after user provided an ids list,
I will test your code now.

Comment: unfortunately when I call list_of_values as a list to my function to filter a column of data, it doesn't do anything, do you have any idea?

Comment: How can i? you did not provide enough code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am going to filter data frame on list_val, as of     df= df.query("id in @list_val") 
But it doesn't apply to this, and does nothing

Answer (score -1):

you can use, c variable is numbers to input, you can change:

```
list = []
c= 5
while  c > 0:
    x = input("PLease enter numbers")
    list.append(x)
    print(x)
    c = c - 1

list
```